# MQTT topic subscription

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

I am using MQTT and activemq in which whenever message published on MQTT topic it will transfer to Activemq queue, below is my code.

```
<destinationInterceptors>
<virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    <virtualDestinations>
        <compositeTopic name="LOCAL.FOO.*">
            <forwardTo>
                <queue physicalName="LOCAL.FOO" />                      
            </forwardTo>
        </compositeTopic>
    </virtualDestinations>
</virtualDestinationInterceptor>
```

at the same time another application subscribing same **MQTT Topic** but that application doesn't get any message from topic but queue can get a message.
So after activemq subscription no one can subscribe the same topic? If this is the case then what would be solution.

I dont have any idea about QoS level and retain falg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that this topic may also be used for subscriptions. There is a `forwardOnly` attribute that is `true` by default.

```
<compositeTopic name="LOCAL.FOO.*" forwardOnly="false">
    <forwardTo>
         <queue physicalName="LOCAL.FOO" />                      
    </forwardTo>
</compositeTopic>
```